# Finding vertical and diagonal lines in binary matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a binary matrix, say:

```
matrix=double(rand(100,100)>0.7);
```

I want to find all "diagonal lines" of 1's (from bottom left to top right) of length 2 or more elements in this matrix and set all other 1's to 0, so that I get another matrix with only those diagonal lines.

I want to do the same for vertical lines.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `conv2` to detect the lines:

```
% your data
M=double(rand(100,100)>0.7);
%length you want to detect
n=2;
kernel=eye(n);
%detect diagonal ones from top left to bottom right
lines=conv2(M,eye(n),'same')==sum(kernel(:));
```

For diagonals going the other direction, use `kernel=fliplr(eye(n));` instead of `kernel=eye(n);`

For vertical and horizontal lines use `kernel=ones(n,1);` or `kernel=ones(1,n);`

The kernels are matrices containing what you want to detect:

```
>> kernel=eye(n)

kernel =

     1     0
     0     1

>> kernel=fliplr(eye(n))

kernel =

     0     1
     1     0

>> kernel=ones(n,1)

kernel =

     1
     1

>> kernel=ones(1,n)

kernel =

     1     1
```

Note that for the second diagonal the marked position might be a bit confusing, because convolution works with rectangles. Inputting

```
[0 0 0;
0 1 0;
1 0 0]
```

It will return:

```
[0 0 0;
1 0 0;
0 0 0]
```

Marking the top left of the rectangles where a diagonal was found. Now having code to identify the diagonals, again convolution can be used to create the intended matrix:

```
M=(conv2(double(conv2(M,kernel,'valid')==sum(kernel(:))),kernel,'full'))>0
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work. Imagine an input of [0 1 0; 1 0 0; 0 0 0]. That would be detected as horizontal or vertical in your example, right? I believe you have to separate horizontal and vertical kernels.

Comment: @Suever: I think you confused my simplified 3 by 3 example image with the kernel. Replaced it with the example from the question to avoid confusion. Otherwise I don't understand your comment.

Comment: maybe I caught you mid-edit. At one point you had the kernel set to be [0 1 0; 1 0 1; 0 1 0] for horizontal/vertical at once (at least that's how it read). Clearer now.

Comment: @Suever: That was my "example image", removed it because it really looks like a kernel.

Comment: wow..great! That works fine, thanks for the fast answer. I edited my post since I realized I'm only interested in diagonal lines from left to right :).

Comment: Never saw a diagonal going from left to right, that would be horizontal ;) I assume you mean from top left to bottom right?

Comment: Then `M2` is what you want

Comment: Yes, I checked it, M2 is exactly what I want..works perfect, thanks! But I'm trying to do the same for vertical lines, any idea how to do this @Daniel :-/?

Comment: @holistic: I have rephrased my answer and code, now containing the corresponding kernels to detect both diagonals, vertical and horizontal.

Comment: @Daniel: Awesome and simple answer, thanks so much!! I was trying to figure out how to do this for 2 hours :).

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2D convolution combined with some fancy kernels to detect this. The basic idea is to craft a kernel that looks like the feature you're trying to detect.

First of all, there are two types of diagonals to detect:

1. top left to bottom right
2. top right to bottom left.

We can design a kernel to detect that first type:

```
kernel = [1 0 0;
          0 1 0;
          0 0 1];
```

This is simply the identity matrix (`eye(3)`), if we convole this with your input.

```
conv2(matrix, eye(3), 'same');
```

If we do this to the identity matrix as a test, we can see the result of the convolution

[image]

You can clearly see that the pixels that are part of the diagonal have values > 1. We can then convert this to a binary matrix indicating whether a pixel is along the diagonal. You also want to ensure that the current pixel is *also* 1.

```
is_top_left_to_bottom_right = conv2(matrix, eye(3), 'same') > 1 & logical(matrix);
```

In a similar way, we can flip the kernel to detect diagonals going the other way.

```
is_top_right_to_bottom_left = conv2(matrix, fliplr(eye(3)), 'same') > 1 & logical(matrix);
```

Then you can look at either independently or join them with a logical `or`

```
is_diagonal = is_top_left_to_bottom_right | is_top_right_to_bottom_left;
```

For horizontal and vertical lines you can use the following kernels in a similar way as the above (remember that I said at the beginning that you want the kernel to look like the feature you're trying to detect!).

```
horizontal = [0 0 0
              1 1 1
              0 0 0];

vertical = [0 1 0 
            0 1 0
            0 1 0];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Code works fine, although I misspecified my question and I need diagonal lines from bottom left to top right only. How do I have to modify your code?

Comment: @holistic read the entire answer. You'll see that I clearly separate the two. Top right to bottom left is the same as bottom left to top right.

Comment: Ah sorry, bottom left to top right is top right to bottom left :). I tested your code, but it seems there are still some single 1's in the resulting matrix e.g. is_top_left_to_bottom_right.

Comment: @holistic are you looking for diagonals that are all ones **or** all zeros?

Comment: Sorry, maybe it wasn't clear enough in my question, I edited it. I meant diagonal lines consisting of 1's of at least length 2 from bottom left to top right.

Comment: @holistic Got it. Updated now.